# how to group model data based on same values in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a model class

```
class PlayerScore(models.Model):
    number=models.IntegerField()
    points=models.FloatField(default=0)
    player=models.ForeignKey('Player')
```

I want to group the data for the same value of **number** field.
for ex. if data in db is like

```
number | points | player_id
-------+--------+----------
     1 |     45 |         1 
     1 |     68 |         2
     2 |     79 |         3
     2 |     70 |         4
```

my query should return

```
[{"number":1, "records": [{"points":45,"player_id":1},{"points":68,"player_id":2}]},
 {"number":2, "records" :[{"points":79,"player_id":3},{"points":70,"player_id":4}]}]
```

please suggest how to write query for this ??

Answer (score 3):

If you want compute it on database level, it can be done only using raw db query. But you can also achieve it in python.

First, get list of all records sorted by `number`:

```
PlayerScore.objects.order_by('number')
```

now, using `values` to get all objects as dictionary, so we can group them together in more convenient way:

```
PlayerScore.objects.order_by('number').values() # or you can list only relevant fields inside values
```

Now, using groupby from itertools we can build our result:

```
from itertools import groupby

values = [
    {'number': k, 'records': list(g)} for k, g in # we are converting iterator returned from groupby into desired list of dictionaries
    groupby(PlayerScore.objects.order_by('number').values(), lambda x: x['number'])
]
```

Comment: this is a really good answer! however, it doesn't work well for methods like get_queryset. i ended up subclassing list and adding the attribute model and the method all, which returns self.

Comment: Right now there are better ways to achieve that, using for example array aggregations or `ArraySubquery` on compatible databases (for now postgresql-only). Some day I may post full updated answer...