# How to group results into array based on similar values, Django Model/Serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

also: [how to group model data based on same values in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824946/how-to-group-model-data-based-on-same-values-in-django)

also 2: [Group serializer results based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165051/group-serializer-results-based-on-value)

Like the others above I need a results returned in a particular way. I would like to group together results which contain a similar value for one column.

As stated above I would like to take this:

```
 album |             title |    singer
-------+-------------------+----------
     1 |  exampleSongTitle |   someone 
     1 |  exampleSongTitle |   sometwo
     2 |  exampleSongTitle | somethree
     2 |  exampleSongTitle |   someone
```

and get this

```
[
  {
    "album": 1,
    "tracks": [
      {
        "title": exampleSongTitle,
        "singer": someone
      },
      {
        "title": exampleSongTitle,
        "singer": sometwo
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "album": 2,
    "tracks": [
      {
        "title": exampleSongTitle,
        "singer": somethree
      },
      {
        "title": exampleSongTitle,
        "singer": someone
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My Model:

```
class Songs(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(db_column='Title', max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)
    album = models.CharField(db_column='Album', max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)
    singer = models.CharField(db_column='Singer', max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Songs'
```

The Album Value will be the value that is same on tracks which are from the same album.

Comment: Can you share your models?

Comment: just updated question with model

Comment: Have you thought about adding an `Album` model and a `Singer` model and having foreign keys to those models? It would make this kind of thing simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the table appears to be fairly flat, you will have to do this formatting/grouping after getting the results from the database. You can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to do this

```
result = []
for album, songs in itertools.groupby(Song.objects.order_by('album'), lambda s: s.album):
    result.append({
        "album": album,
        "tracks": [{
            "title": song.title,
            "singer": song.singer
        } for song in songs]
    })
```

Comment: Performing the aggregation in memory isn't great if the query returns a very large dataset. Depending on the database you're using, you could level the DBMS's aggregation functions (e.g., `ArrayAgg` if you're using Postgres)